# how to convert [NSManagedObject] to nsmutable array (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios9, nsmanagedobject

i am using coredata in my app. i am storing 50 city in my core data. now i want to use search bar. which was working well with array. and i am using filtering for that. here is my code for that

```
arrcity.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({ (obj, _, _) -> Void in

            if let city : SelectCityModel = obj as? SelectCityModel
            {
                if city.city.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(self.searchtext.lowercaseString) != nil
                {
                    self.searchcity?.addObject(city)
                }
            }
        })
```

now i want to do same process but i have [nsmanagedobject] people. so how can i do this. it will be ease if is there any way to convert [NsmanagedObject] to nsmutablearry.

here is my code

```
if (people.count > 0)
        {

            people.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({ (obj, _, _) -> Void in

                if let city : SelectCityModel = obj as? SelectCityModel
                {
                    if city.city.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(self.searchtext.lowercaseString) != nil
                    {
                        self.searchcity?.addObject(city)
                    }
                }
            })

        }
```

but here var people = NSManagedObject so how can i convert it?

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray` is not related to a Swift Array.

But you could use the Swift Array with a native enumerator, for example

```
people.forEach { [unowned self] (object) -> () in
  if object is SelectCityModel
  {
    if object.city.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(self.searchtext.lowercaseString) != nil
    {
      self.searchcity?.addObject(city)
    }
  }
}
```

If people is always `[SelectCityModel]` cast it to that type in the fetch line and omit the type check in the `forEach` closure. The check if `people > 0` is not needed either.

A more convenient way is to use the `filter` and `map` functions.

```
self.searchcity = people.filter({$0.city.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(self.searchtext.lowercaseString) != nil}).map{ $0.city }
```

Comment: this is my fetch line    let results =
            try moc.executeFetchRequest(personfetch)
            people = results as! [NSManagedObject]      @vadian how can i store this in array

Comment: Just write `people = results as! [SelectCityModel]` then you can delete the `object is SelectCityModel` check

Comment: its not working men is it possible to cast Nsmanagedobject to nsdictionary ??

Comment: In Swift the native collection types are much easier to handle. You can even use the `filter` function rather than the enumeration loop which is much more performant. What error do you get?